# RabbitMq : Is there a way to apply policy on all virtual host in cluster environment for queue mirroring?

Tags: rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange, rabbitmqctl

In RabbitMQ,

If I want to mirror queue in cluster environment I use below command :

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy ha-all "" '{"ha-mode":"all","ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}'
```

This command will apply policy to all queues of virtual host `"\"`.

If I have to apply the policy for specific virtual host say "foo"  I use:

```
rabbitmqctl set_policy -p "foo" ha-all "" '{"ha-mode":"all","ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}'
```

Question :

Is there a way to apply policy on all virtual host in cluster environment for queue mirroring?

Comment: did you find the answer to this?

Answer (score 3):

If you are running on a *nix environment,  the following should work

```
rabbitmqctl list_vhosts | while read line ; do rabbitmqctl set_policy -p "$line" ha-all "" '{"ha-mode":"all","ha-sync-mode":"automatic"}'; done
```

This will pipe each line of the output into your rabbitmqctrl command.